# Copy the images to the public folder after form submit with PLupload in a custom module

Tags: 7, forms, files

I have a custom module to create galleries using PLupload to upload multiple files. These files have a ".tmp" extension in my "/tmp" folder.

Here is an extract of my $form_state['values']:

```
[0] => Array(
    [tmppath] => temporary://p17g31n52jo4fvj31ds01efd189b4.tmp
    [tmpname] => p17g31n52jo4fvj31ds01efd189b4.tmp
    [name] => photo_1.jpg
    [status] => done
)
```

How do I save the files in my public folder with the good extension (like .jpg)?
I've tried using [file_save_upload()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save_upload/7) or [file_copy()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_copy/7) but without success.

Can anyone help me?

I'm on a local server (wamp) as administrator with all permissions. The folders (tmp and site/default) are writable.

I copy here some extracts of my code.

*hook_form() :*

```
$form['create']['photos'] = array(
    '#type' => 'plupload',
    '#title' => 'Photos',
    '#upload_validators' => array(
        'file_validate_extensions' => array('jpg jpeg gif png'),
    ),
    '#plupload_settings' => array(
        'runtimes' => 'html5',
        'chunk_size' => '1mb',
    ),
);
```

*hook_form_validate() :*

```
$file = file_save_upload('photos', array(
    'file_validate_is_image' => array(),
    'file_validate_extensions' => array('png gif jpg jpeg'),
));

if ($file) {
    if ($file = file_move($file, 'public://')) {
        $form_state['storage']['file'] = $file;
    } else {
        form_set_error('file', t('Failed to write the uploaded file the site\'s file folder.'));
    }
} else {
    form_set_error('file', t('No file was uploaded.'));
}
```

It returns "No file was uploaded." I don't understand what I should put as first arguments to the *file_save_upload* function.

Comment: File uploading can depend heavily on system information.  Can you add a description of the server, your file paths, permissions etc?  Also, you should describe the error output you get; there are lots of (wrong) ways to use `file_save_upload()` and `file_copy()`.

Comment: Hi Seth ans thank you for your interest. I have edited my post with several additional informations...

Answer (score 1):

I finally manage to do what I want...

I didn't understand how to use `file_copy` ans its `$destination` argument. We can put a file path, not only a folder path. So, I can save my file.jpg correctly.

My code :

```
$values = $form_state['values']['create'];
$photos_count = count($values['photos']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $photos_count; $i++) {
    $path = $values['photos'][$i]['tmppath'];
    $name = $values['photos'][$i]['name'];
    // set file datas as an object to pass it in file_copy()
    $file = (object)array(
        'uid' => 0,
        'uri' => $path,
        'filemime' => file_get_mimetype($path),
        'status' => 1
    );
    // copy the file in the correct folder
    if ($file = file_copy($file, $filepath . '/' . $name)) {
        drupal_set_message('Success');
    } else {
        drupal_set_message('Error', 'error');
    }
    // set the field datas for saving the node with an array
    $node->field_album_photos[$node->language][$i] = (array)$file;
}
```

Have a nice day !